# In Portal games, do you always exit a portal at a right angle to its surface?

Tags: portal-series

Please help settle a debate between a group of friends.  In Portal games, is exit velocity always normal to the portal surface being exited?

More importantly: please offer some kind of undeniable proof that will allow the debate among friends to end.  I am nowhere near a machine with Portal installed for several days, but my memory of the series is that yes, exit velocity always is normal to the portal surface.  Put more simply: if the exit portal is on the ground, no matter how you enter the entrance portal, you will come out of the exit portal moving vertically up.  (Granted, you may be able to move out of that vertical column a split second later because of video game physics that allow forward motion to be initiated in midair, but if you do not press any movement controls after exit, you will rise/fall in a perfectly vertical column and end up re-entering the floor portal you just exited).

Comment: Added the test with the ball as you suggested

Comment: If you voted for my (now self-deleted) wrong answer, go vote for WizLiz's awesome answer below, which *uses science* to prove the angle matters in both games.

Comment: @Jaydles thanks regardless for your help.  Both of you guys rock!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**No, angle of penetration matters in both games.**

The only online [article we could find covering this](http://www.dissectingdesign.com/game-design/portal-2-physics-made-it-worse-than-portal/) suggests that the angle matters in Portal 2, but did not in Portal 1, but after *doing science,* we can clearly demonstrate that the article's wrong - entry angle matters in both games.

Since you asked for undeniable proof, the following videos show you this mechanic in Portal 1.

### 4 tests on the lastest version of Portal 1

Tested on June the 6th, 2014 :

- [Using a ball instead of Chell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GFBFSqcx9g) :
  **(If you are only going to watch one video, make it this one)** I tested this on advanced chamber 17. The ball falls through the blue
  portal and gain momentum (while falling). During the fall I place an
  orange portal above the slanted surface, as soon as the ball comes
  out of the orange portal I place another orange portal on the slanted
  surface giving the ball an angle of penetration (45° I assume), the
  ball is then ejected out of the blue portal but not vertically, it's
  propulsed against the wall just in front of me. I repeated this
  operation several times with different portal placement in order to
  be sure that this was not due to a collision of some sort and it's
  not, the outcome should be quite easy to reproduce if you want to
  test it by yourself.
- [Portal placed vertically](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFF_qEbiOG8) : If speed vector was normal to the wall, I should
  not pass through the emancipation grill
- [Portal placed horizontally](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAVduZmK9d4) : I use the Angle of entry in the orange portal to land way further than the blue one.

**To finish,** in Portal 2 angle matters aswell but it's way easier to show it since its part of the gameplay with lasers.

### Taking advantage of Angles of penetration in game

**1. On the playground** (a map designed with the purpose of learning those mechanics)

[Example on vertical surface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeq7qK2tKhM) : In this example you can clearly see that the angle of penetration is conserved at the exit, allowing to reach the plateform on the left when exiting the portal.

[Example on horizontal surface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qKXbjgO0KI) : In this example you enter twice the blue portal and goes out of the orange portal at 2 different angles (and speed but that's not the point here) allowing you to reach the top plateform. If the exit velocity vector was normal to the surface you wouldn't be able to reach the top plateform at all.

**2. In an official chamber**

This mechanic is for example what allows to finish the [room 15 in 1 step in the least step challenge](http://youtu.be/k4aTUBrDRlg?t=2m31s). Once you get into the "loop", you can place a blue portal on the ground and reach the elevator thanks to the momentum and the angle of exit (given by the angle of penetration). Again here, if the exit velocity vector was normal to the ground, when the blue portal was placed Chell should just have jumped vertically. Obviously it's not the case since she reaches the elevator.

Comment: The second one is two different speeds, not angles.

Comment: @OrangeDog if you watch closely, the first angle of exit in the second video does not allow to reach the top plateform, the speed is indeed a factor but the angles of exit are different

Comment: @WizLiz, Aperture would approve of your use of *science* here! I'm starting to think you may be right, but one thing's still throwing me - you can move in the air in Portal, so it's not clear to me that the entry angle is the only variable, as opposed to the fact that you come out facing that way and moving in that direction due to pushing the stick that way on *exit*.  Again, not entirely sure - just trying to dissect the possibilities.

Comment: @Jaydles its true but the movement is limited, Ill upload a last video showing how far you can go by moving in the air with a better momentum than the other video, you cant reach as far, angle is truly needed.

Comment: @Jaydles Done, if you feel the need to test any further I'm willing to try anything. Don't hesistate to tell me if you want to clear any doubt.

Comment: I don't think there's any doubt angular momentum is preserved when you go through the portal, but the only way to truly test wither or not the angle of penetration is preserved is tilt Chell on a slanted surface and then have her stick her head through a portal and see if her view on the other side comes out as 90 degrees or at an angle.

Comment: @z' Thats a good question, I'll try to see if its possible to test it, maybe piling cube under a slanted surface then moving the portal along. I'll try and see if there is somewhere in the game where this can be tested, I'm curious now

Comment: Here is one idea that would remove any doubt about player movement vs momentum.  Drop an object (preferably a sphere if those exist) straight down, some significant distance.  The object should eventually hit a portal on a surface 45-deg to its trajectory.  The exit portal should be on a horizontal surface.  Observe the exit trajectory of the sphere from the exit portal.  Make sense?

Comment: @The111, perfect sense - it eliminates the difficulty in controlling for post-exit controller movement, and limits the outcome to an easily observable binary.

Comment: @Jaydles Last test with the ball tend to confirm what I affirm =)

Comment: major props for the testing.

Comment: @WizLiz, just to confirm - that's portal 1, yes?  (Just triple checking, since it breaks my heart a tiny bit to self-delete a 25-vote answer, but *I must respect the testing*!!

Comment: @Jaydles yes it is ;)

Comment: Well done.  Didn't take the time to watch all your videos, but you implemented my suggested ball test to perfection!  For science! :-)

Comment: @The111 They're all fairly short (~10sec). The ball idea was grear, I'm glad there was a rool in the game allowing to test this =D

Comment: The portal loop in the room 15 video certainly looks like the angle is redirected. That might be due to Chell banging her head on the ceiling, though I feel like banging your head on the ceiling also had a big impact on the horizontal component of velocity.

Comment: @WizLiz Yeah I glanced at most of them but realized none from player POV would convince me because of air movement and that weird camera rotation thing that happens when you go through an out of axis portal.  I originally wanted an outside view anyway, so I realized using a non-player object would kill both the POV *and* the movement concerns.  Thanks again for putting it together. :-)

Comment: There is an option in the settings menus of all the versions of the game I have played that specifically pulls the player into a course more normal to the surface of the portal. Some puzzles are much harder when it is turned off. This is Portal 1, I haven't checked the menus in Portal 2. It is called something like "portal funnel."

Comment: Call me childish but isn't there a better word than penetration?

Comment: Call me childish but I thought that was an awesome choice of words. :-)

Comment: In the middle of test chamber 15 there are angled panels and a pellet. Entry on the angled panel clearly exits the portal at the same angle, and not the normal to the wall.